# Local Apache Spark on heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku, apache-spark

I have a problem running the apache spark in local mode on Heroku with Spring. My issue is:

```
@Configuration
public class SparkConfig {

private String master = "local";

@Bean
public JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext() {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("local")
            .setMaster(master);
    return new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'javaSparkContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'javaSparkContext' defined in class path resource [com/sensorservice/config/SparkConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext]: Factory method 'javaSparkContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: System memory 326631424 must be at least 471859200. Please increase heap size using the --driver-memory option or spark.driver.memory in Spark configuration.
```

I tried to modify the parameters Spark related to memory but this had no effect. It is possible to launch Spark free Heroku?

Comment: What did you try to increase driver-memory?

Comment: Yes. I changed parameters:
spark.driver.cores, spark.driver.memory, spark.executor.memory, spark.storage.memoryFraction and spark.memory.storageFraction.
Did not work. I wonder if Heroku does not limit the memory at startup or if the supplied resources are sufficient to launch Spark.

Comment: free heroku dyno has 512MB of RAM and spark need at least 450MB. I think even if you try to increase driver-memory you will lack of memory